# Custom Clone method hides inherited member?

Tags: c#

```
public interface IMyInterface : ICloneable
{
    IMyInterface Clone();
}
```

> 'TestApp.IMyInterface.Clone()' hides inherited member
>   'System.ICloneable.Clone()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was
>   intended.

I need my interface to be compatible with `ICloneable`. How do I resolve this ambiguity?

### UPDATE

Consider this concrete class, implementing `IMyInterface`. The idea is that it should have a working `Clone` method **and** implement `ICloneable` so that any method accepting an `ICloneable` will still work!

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    #region ICloneable interface
    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }
    #endregion

    public IMyInterface Clone()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Now, this compiles, but there is this warning. How do I get rid of the warning *and* keep the compatibility with the `ICloneable` interface?

Comment: Use the `new` keyword?

Comment: Or MyClone instead of Clone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that warning because `ICloneable` specifies a `Clone` method that returns an `object`; not an `IMyInterface`.  Your `Clone` method has a different signature, and therefore hides the one specified by the `ICloneable` interface.  You could just leave it off:

```
public interface IMyInterface : ICloneable
{
}
```

If you need both, then use the `new` keyword:

```
public interface IMyInterface : ICloneable
{
    new IMyInterface Clone();
}
```

Make your implementation look like this:

```
public class MyInterface : IMyInterface
{
    object ICloneable.Clone() // explicit interface implementation
    {
        return this.Clone(); // calls the other Clone method
    }

    public IMyInterface Clone()
    {
        return new MyInterface
        {
            // member initializations
        };
    }
}
```

This will satisfy both interfaces, and not duplicate code in each `Clone` implementation.

Usage:

```
IMyInterface i = new MyInterface();
MyInterface c = new MyInterface();

object x = i.Clone(); // Calling Clone on i calls the ICloneable.Clone implementation
IMyInterface y = c.Clone(); // Calling Clone on c calls the IMyInterface.Clone implementation
```

Comment: No, I need both methods. In a concrete class this would be no problem. I would simply add `object ICloneable.Clone();` and `MyConcreteClass Clone()`.

Comment: I have amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. The solution was to add the `new` keyword just like you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

This compiler *warning* is telling you that your code is confusing; people who read it may not be sure whether you're trying to override the base member or create a new one.

You should add the `new` keyword to clarify that you're creating a new member.

Note that classes which implement your interface will need to implement *both* `Clone()` methods; at least one of them will need to be implemented explicitly.

Comment: This is what I have done. Adding `new` in front of the declaration seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has the same name as the IClonable interface specification for Clone(). You should consider making your IMyInterface specify more explicitly what your clone does. example: DeepCopy() / ShallowCopy().
Or you can simply replace the base Clone() by using:

```
   public void new Clone()
```